# How do I "fork" a Stream in .NET?

Tags: c#, stream, clone, memorystream

As [discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084813/why-a-binarywriter-closes-the-outer-stream-on-disposal-and-how-to-prevent-that), when a BinaryReader or BinaryWriter gets closed, its underlying Stream get closed as well (aargh).  Consider this situation: a routine `R` is passed a MemoryStream, say `M`; I would like to write some stuff to `M` and then pass it to another routine for more processing (not necessarily writing). For convenience, I'd like to wrap `M` in a BinaryWriter to do my writing. After writing, I'm done with the BinaryWriter but not with `M`.

```
void R(MemoryStream M)
{
    using (B = new BinaryWriter(M))
    {
        // write some stuff using B
    }

    S(M);  // now pass M to another routine for further processing
}
```

But, I can't dispose of the BinaryStream without closing `M`.

Q: Is there a way to do any of the following?

- extract the underlying byte[] from a MemoryStream,
- clone a Stream
- reopen a Stream after it's been closed

Comment: I don't know C#, but in Java, you'd simply just abandon without closing the BinaryWriter.  Doesn't the using{...} construct force closing? Then don't use that construct!

Comment: P.S. But you do need to ensure you flush the BinaryWriter before you abandon it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to several who suggested ToArray, I was led to right answer, which is `M.GetBuffer'. ToArray is not too bad, but it

- makes a copy
- gets only part of the buffer

GetBuffer just grabs a reference to the underlying byte[], which is what I'm after.

Answer (score 7):

You should better get the underlying byte[] buffer using

```
byte[] buffer = ms.GetBuffer();
```

And then copy the byte data using the Array.Copy() method.
You are free to create a new stream with it.

Comment: I don't understand why you're saying it's better to use GetBuffer and then make a copy using Array.Copy.  If I wanted a copy I'd just use ToArray.

Comment: From MSDN doc 
This method omits unused bytes in MemoryStream from the array. To get the entire buffer, use the GetBuffer method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx

Comment: The above "This Method" refers to the  MemoryStream.ToArray()

Answer (score 5):

You can use things like the `MiscUtil.IO.NonClosingStreamWrapper` in [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/), which wraps a `Stream` and simply ignores `Close`/`Dispose` requests. For just this purpose.

```
void R(MemoryStream M)
{
    using (B = new BinaryWriter(new NonClosingStreamWrapper(M)))
    {
        // write some stuff using B
    }

    S(M);  // now pass M to another routine for further processing
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- Call M.ToArray() to get the stream as an array of bytes.
- Subclass BinaryWriter and override the Dispose method to prevent closing of the child stream

Comment: Can't you just avoid calling close/Dispose?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add it in here, a very simple solution would be **not** to Dispose() the writer.

```
void R(MemoryStream M)
{
    B = new BinaryWriter(M);

    // write some stuff using B        
    B.Flush();
    S(M);  // now pass M to another routine for further processing
}
```

Now you only have to worry about keeping B in scope, which it will be during R().

This may not be the best solution here, but it is worth noting that the Readers and Writers don't need Disposing themselves.

Comment: But make sure you call B.flush() after you've finished with it in case it hasn't pushed everything through to M.  (That's what would be needed in Java, no idea about C#)

Comment: OK, Adrian & Marc, I forgot to Flush().

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat naive approach is to use

```
byte buf[] = MemoryStream.ToArray();
```

To copy the stream contents to a byte array. You can turn it back into a stream with

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buf);
```

Comment: Worth emphasising : this method works on a closed stream as well as a live one.

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_21554071.html) M.Clone(); should work. But i may be wrong...

Comment: -1 for posting to a website which doesn't allow viewing it's contents for free, which is pretty much useless