# Why is my FileStream object being disposed of when I'm "using" a BinaryReader object?

Tags: .net, using-statement, objectdisposedexception

Consider the following function:

```
    private int GetSomethingFromFile(FileStream fs) 
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return br.ReadInt32();
        }
    }
```

A FileStream object is passed in as a parameter and a BinaryReader is declared with a using statement.  When I try to use that FileStream object, after calling this function, it throws a System.ObjectDisposedException.  Why is that FileStream object being disposed of along with the BinaryReader object?

Comment: Related questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084813/why-a-binarywriter-closes-the-outer-stream-on-disposal-and-how-to-prevent-that) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633672/how-do-i-fork-a-stream-in-net)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a very good question, and I don't know why it was decided that this was how it should be, but alas it is documented to be this way:

**[BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) class**

> [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.close.aspx): Closes the current reader **and the underlying stream**.

If you check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633672/how-do-i-fork-a-stream-in-net/1633835#1633835) to the question [How do I “fork” a Stream in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633672/how-do-i-fork-a-stream-in-net) then you'll see that he refers to a class called NonClosingStreamWrapper in a library called [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) that @[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has written that you can use to wrap around the stream to prevent it from being closed.

You would use it like this (for your example):

```
private int GetSomethingFromFile(FileStream fs) 
{
    using (var wrapper = new NonClosingStreamWrapper(fs))
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(wrapper))
    {
        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return br.ReadInt32();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that sucks.  I need that stream after I call the function.  I'm just supposed to go against recommended practice and forgo the using statement?

Comment: To be honest, either way is a "hack", either you drop the using-statement, or you make the wrapper class ignore that call. I have been using a similar wrapper myself though so that's what I would do.

Answer (score 1):

Because disposing the binary reader disposes its underlying stream.

Use "using" in the caller method instead.

The reason is arbitrary: .NET class library is implemented this way.