# Stream was not readable error

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, memorystream

I am getting the message **"Stream was not readable"** on the statement:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
```

I have tried the tips posted here without success.  Thanks for the help.

This is my code:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Conflict));
//Serialize Conflicts array to memorystream as XML
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
    {
        foreach (Conflict ct in Conflicts)      
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, ct);

        sw.Flush(); //Site tip
        ms.Position = 0;  //Site tip
    }
    //Retrieve memory stream to string
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
        string conflictXml = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}</NewDataSet>",
```

Comment: Formatted code would be easier to follow and help debug

Comment: StreamWriter and StreamReader both close the underlying stream when disposed of, as such, when you get to trying to read from the stream that was closed when you disposed of the StreamWriter, the stream is no longer open for reading or writing. Unfortunately I am not at my computer now, but other answers on this site has classes for wrapping the underlying stream to prevent it from being closed.

Comment: A wrapper class can be found linked to from this answer of mine earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261123/why-is-my-filestream-object-being-disposed-of-when-im-using-a-binaryreader-obj/5261202#5261202

Answer (score 33):

When this block of code completes, it will also dispose the attached MemoryStream

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
{
    foreach (Conflict ct in Conflicts)
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, ct);
    sw.Flush(); //Site tip
    ms.Position = 0;  //Site tip
}
```

Remove the using statement, and dispose the stream manually after you are done with it

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);

foreach (Conflict ct in Conflicts)
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, ct);
sw.Flush(); //Site tip
ms.Position = 0;  //Site tip

// other code that uses MemoryStream here...

sw.Dispose();
```

Comment: In .Net 4.5 there's a StreamWriter overload where can be specified to leave the stream open: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg712853(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx

Comment: And don't forget to enclose everything in `try/finally` block and add `sw.Dispose()` in `finally` block. You will need to define `StreamWriter sw` outside `try/finally` block.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead (assuming Conflicts is of type `List<Conflict>`):

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Conflict>));
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, Conflicts);
string conflictXml = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```

Comment: Will this only work with a generic collection?  I'm stuck right now with .Net 1.1.